# Stuck trying to display info on a CLI from an API that uses a hash and a nested hash

Tags: json, ruby

Trying to display second level information about characters from this [Futurama API](https://api.sampleapis.com/futurama/characters).

Currently using this code to get information:

```
def self.character 
    uri = URI.parse(URL)
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
     data = JSON.parse(response.body)
     data.each do |c| 
        Character.new(c["name"], c["gender"], c["species"], c["homePlanet"], c["occupation"], c["info"], c["sayings"])
     end
end
```

I'm then stuck either returning (gender and species) from the nested hash (if character id > 8) or the original hash (character id < 8) when using this code:

```
def character_details(character)
    puts "Name: #{character.name["first"]} #{character.name["middle"]} #{character.name["last"]}"
    puts "Species: #{character.info["species"]}" 
    puts "Occupation: #{character.homePlanet}"
    puts "Gender: #{character.info["gender"]}"  
    puts "Quotes:" 
        character.sayings.each_with_index do |s, i|
            iplusone = i + 1 
        puts "#{iplusone}. #{s} "
        end

end
```

Not sure where or what logic to use to get the correct information to display.

Comment: Can u show us the definition of Character?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a problem when save `c['info]` in `Character.new(c["name"], c["gender"], c["species"], c["homePlanet"], c["occupation"], c["info"], c["sayings"])`

I'm running your code and I see `info` does not exist in the response of API, the gender should be accessed in character.gender

```rb
irb(main):037:0> character.gender
=> "Male"
irb(main):039:0> character.species
=> "Human"
```

I don't understand this comment: (if character id > 8) or the original hash (character id < 8) Can you explain us what u need do?

Comment: I actually figured it out, I'll share the (inelegant) code that worked. I added it to commit. Sorry I'm still new in these parts, but the beginning that worked. 

i used: def character_details(character, id)
    id = id.to_i
    if id >= 8